# argparse argument order issue

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `subparsers` to implement the following function:

```
import argparse 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='dj')
parser.add_argument('--log','-l',type=str, help='log file')
parser.add_argument('--parser','-p',type=bool, nargs='?', const=True, default=False, help='wheher parsing a dj file or not')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='execute specified command')
###############################################################################
parser_rt = subparsers.add_parser('run_test', help='kick off a case')
parser_rt.add_argument('--test', '-t', type=str, help='test case name')
parser_rt.add_argument('--config','-c', type=str, help='config name')
parser_rt.set_defaults(func=run_test)
```

everything is fine when kicking off the command:

```
dj -p -l dj.log run_test -t testa -c configa
```

or

```
dj -l dj.log run_test -t testa -c configa
```

However, issue was popping up when running the command:

```
dj -l dj.log -p run_test -t testa -c configa
```

Here is error:

```
usage: dj [-h] [--log log] [--parser [PARSER]]
       {run_test}...
dj: error: invalid choice: 'testa' (choose from 'run_test')
```

It seems that the issue is related to the position of `-p`.

Comment: thank tomerikoo.  the issue was printed when '-p' is next to 'run_test'.  As I know, arguments should not be sensitive to position.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error and the library's name is 'argparse' not 'argparser'. Please fix your code so that it is runnable.

Comment: A subparsers argument is a special kind of `positional` argument.  Therefore its position does matter.  In the problem case it gets next available nonflag string - after the one that `-p` has consumed..  Using variable `nargs` like `?` around positionals is unwise.

Answer (score 2):

By defining `-p` as `nargs='?', const=True, default=False` it ***still consumes the next argument***, just not doing anything with it...

When it has `run_test` after it, it is consumed as an argument and not as a subparser and then `-t` is not defined either...

To overcome this, simply use the idiomatic way for defining "flag" arguments which is either [`store_true` or `store_false`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) as the `action`. So to fix your parser, change to:

```
parser.add_argument('--parser','-p', action='store_true', help='wheher parsing a dj file or not')
```

When you ran `-p -l` there was no issue because `argparse` knows to differentiate arguments using the `-`. So in this case `-p` had no value and `-l` started a new argument. `run_test` was taken as a value before `argparse` checked it for a subparser.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `-p` might take an argument. Is that intended or do you rather want just a flag?

```py
    parser.add_argument('--parser','-p', action="store_true", help='whether parsing a dj file or not')
```

When you run `dj -l dj.log -p run_test -t testa -c configa` the parser thinks that `run_test` is an argument to `-p`.